# summingDouble on AttributeValue java streams

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream, reduce, entity-attribute-value

I have a List of Map of String, AttributeValue and would like to use `summingDouble` in order to group the keys and find their sum for each keys respectively.

For example,

```
    List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> ls = new ArrayList<Map<String, AttributeValue>>();

    Map<String,AttributeValue> map = new HashMap<String,AttributeValue>();
    map.put("key1", new AttributeValue().withN("1000"));
    map.put("key2", new AttributeValue().withN("1000"));


    ls.add(map);
    Map<String,AttributeValue> map1 = new HashMap<String,AttributeValue>();
    map1.put("key3", new AttributeValue().withN("1000"));
    map1.put("key1", new AttributeValue().withN("2000"));
    ls.add(map1);
```

This should return

```
result = {key1: 3000, key2: 1000, key3: 1000}
```

where key1 is the sum of values for key1.

Tried like the below but getValue in this case is a AttributeValue so it doesn't work.

```
Map<String, Double> result = ls.stream().flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()).collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, summingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Comment: how do you retrieve that double from `AttributeValue`? is there a getter?

Comment: @Eugene Maybe just `getN`?

Comment: @Eugene I'm looking for that answer only.. need help to get double from AttributeValue.. Inorder to extract the double value that is there..

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I guess... so it should be just `entry -> Double.valueOf(entry.getValue().getN())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your groupingBy should be like this:

```
groupingBy(
    Map.Entry::getKey, 
    summingDouble(e -> Double.valueOf(e.getValue().getN())))
```

Comment: ```Map<String, Double> map1 = ls.stream().flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
  .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, summingDouble(e -> Double.valueOf(e.getValue().getN())) ));  ```                                                                    Tried the above but returns ```{key1=2000.0, key2=2000.0, key3=2000.0}```

Comment: @user1712810 what do you expect? look at how you put `ls.add(map)`, then you override values in this *same* `map` and do again a `ls.add(map)`. You probably want a *new* map for `key3` and `key1`